# Symbolic equivalent of chmod 600

Tags: permissions, chmod

The following is often used to set file permissions, a good example being setting a key file to an appropriate permission level to be used by ssh (this being the "octal" form):

```
chmod 600 filename.xyz
```

Would it be a correct equivalent and acceptable practice to use the following instead (this is the "symbolic" form)?

```
chmod a=,u=r filename.xyz
```

The reason I ask is that it seems a bit clearer for code readability. Still not exactly human readable, but no bit mapping needed.

If maximum readibility (and not terseness) were the primary driver, would there be a better option?

Comment: Wow, I just realized that I used 400 instead of 600. 400 would be write only, which would not work for the ssh scenario that I mentioned.

Comment: Heh, not sure whether it's irony... I made the mistake in the question that I was trying to solve via the same question. :-)

Comment: Updated to change 400 to 600.

Comment: I like `chmod a=,u=r filename.xyz` it is easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `a=,u=r`, the order is important. If you accidentally swap the order of `a=` and `u=r` (or the order of `a=` and `u=`), the result would be very different. (Yes, `a` and `u` are pretty far from each other on a QWERTY keyboard, but someone looking at a reference doc and manually typing things in might mess up between the two very similar looking parts.) For maximum readability and safety, I'd be more explicit:

```sh
chmod u=r,go-rwx filename # or go-rwxst
```

The permission components are very different here, and way more explicit, making mistakes less likely to happen. And it doesn't matter if you have `go-rwx` first or `u=r` first.